# Entity Framework 4 + Firebird -> Freezing on Fetch if there is other transaction open

Tags: transactions, firebird, isolation-level

The problem is as folows:

If i am editing a row in IBExpert and dont commit the transaction, the EF just freeze when trying to fetch Data ( Entity.ToList() ). I Would understand if that happened when trying to update the row, but why does the EF cant fetch the commited version of the row?

When hanging, if i commit the transaction in IBExpert, it immediately continue the fetch and everything gets ok.

Steps to reproduce:
1 -> Edit a row in IBExpert or other software.
2 -> Try to FETCH that row in the EF. Its going to freeze until you commit the other transaction .

Its driving me crazy, i cant find solutions anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably all about transaction isolation levels. If you have WAIT option enabled, it will wait until uncommitted transactions are committed when using READ_COMMITTED isolation level (default).

More information: http://fhasovic.blogspot.com/2005/02/transaction-isolation-levels-in.html